# Does Rapidly Calling A Method With Local Variables Eat CPU/Memory?

Tags: performance

Say I have a method  that defines a few objects and variable and initializes them. Would a timer or similar that loops through the method every half second or so eat up memory with the objects and variables constantly being defined and initialized every half second?

If it does would making said objects and variables global save memory or am I completely off track?

Comment: for Memory I think it will till a garbage collection will run, but it won't be a big problem, CPU won't be a problem either if you're just using system timeout or interval functions

Comment: It's really simple: benchmark it.

Comment: Possibly, but at the moment you are presumably creating new instances, globalising them would make those instances common across all methods which could give you all sorts of issues. Unless you are talking huge objects, or a huge amount of equivalent ones, both of which could be addressed in other ways, messing with this would be an extreme violation of the KISS principle.

Comment: The question is hopelessly vague.  But really, no modern computer ever has a problem doing something twice a second.